# Angle brackets are removed after parsing object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object I've stored inside my sessionstorage and it contains a question, and an answer.
I want to read out this question on another page. That is why I'm using storage.
The problem is that because some of the answers contains options with angle brackets like
`'<h1>'` or `'<img>'`, those options are gone after being parsed. It shows nothing or the value between the brackets. I think I know why but I want to know if my suspicion is true, and if true, how I can fix it.

My code:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const element = items[i];
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            const newContainer = containerList.appendChild(div);
            newContainer.classList.add('questionContainer');
            if (Object.keys(element).length == 2) {
                div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="question">${element.questions}</div>
                <div class="yourAnswer right">${element.answer}</div>
                `
            } else {
                div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="question">${element.question}</div>
                <div class="yourAnswer wrong">${element.yourAnswer}</div>
                <div class="correctAnswer">${element.correctAnswer}</div>
                `        
            }
        }
```

So I think it is because I use this div template thing to fill up a new created div which contains the qustion, answer and if wrong, the correct answer. Because it is placed between angled brackets, the brackets from the answer are seen as an actual html tag, instead of an answer.
Is this true and if yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: Escape the angle brackets to their associated HTML entities with `.replaceAll` before interpolating

Comment: Put it in the `innerText` of the element instead of `innerHTML` so the HTML won't be parsed.

Comment: @Barmar, that puts the whole text block into the div

Comment: I mean you have to create the div and then do `div.innerText = element.question;`. Don't do any of this by creating HTML strings.